# Veeam Backup & Replication 9.5: Impossible to add hyper-v host to backup infrastructure (Network path not found, or invalid credentials supplied)

Tags: windows-server-2012, ntlm, veeam, local-security-policy

In the software Backup & Replication 9.5 it was not possible to add the local Hyper-V host (standalone) to the backup infrastructure:

Always gives an error **"Network path not found, or invalid credentials supplied."**

I tried first these tipps: https://www.veeam.com/kb1230
But this solved not my issue...
With a process monitor I saw the application "Veeam.Backup.Satellite.exe" tries to access the file system *\;RdpDr\;:0\192.168.x.x\ADMIN$* with an error "BAD NETWORK NAME".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - getting this error when trying to add a Hyper-V standalone host. My host was running Server 2016 Hyper-V edition (free hyper-V / console only OS).

Found the error to be inability to access the admin$ share... run this command from the host:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=”File and Printer Sharing” new enable=Yes
```

Worked immediately for me after that!

Answer (score 1):

After a long time I could now find the solution myself:
In the Local security Policy->Local Policies->Security Options->
**Network security: Restrict NTLM: Incoming NTLM traffic** was the value set to **Deny all accounts**.
After set the value to **Allow all** it works now :-)